# I need help trying to find a different value in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a maze generator, I am currently trying to spread out the objects evenly without having them overlap. I have already made a function that snaps the coords to a grid. The grid snap is 50 at the moment. What I am having trouble with is trying to make it so that I coords don't overlap. EX: If I already have an object at (100, 100), I dont want another object to go to (100, 100). If you would like the whole file, I can give it to you, but stack overflow wont allow that. The code included for some reason does not work, it really seams like it should though.

```py
objectXLst = []
objectYLst = []
objectXYLst = [(1, 1)]

def check_list(listToCheck, valToCheck):
        objectX = valToCheck[0]
        objectY = valToCheck[1]
        objectXY = valToCheck
        for i in range(len(listToCheck)):
            while listToCheck[i] == objectXY:
                resultForCheck = True
                objectX = divisible_random(0, screenWidth, gridSnapVal)
                objectY = divisible_random(0, screenHeight, gridSnapVal)
                objectXY = (objectX, objectY)
                print("{}, {}, checking".format((objectX, objectY), valToCheck), listToCheck[i])
            else:
                break
        return objectX, objectY
for i in range(int((screenWidth*screenHeight)/gridSnapVal**2)):
        index = 0
        objectX = divisible_random(0, screenWidth, gridSnapVal)
        objectY = divisible_random(0, screenHeight, gridSnapVal)
        counter = 0
        goThru = True
        val = check_list(objectXYLst, (objectX, objectY))
        objectX, objectY = check_list(objectXYLst, (objectX, objectY))
        counter = 0
        if remove1st is True:
            objectXYLst.remove((1, 1))
            remove1st = False
        print(objectX, objectY)
        objectXLst.append(objectX)
        objectYLst.append(objectY)
        objectXYLst.append((objectX, objectY))
        gameObjectsList.append(gameObjects)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Why doesn't the code work, i.e. what happens and what would you like to happen? Do you get the same error in your full code or just the example that you've posted? What have you tried to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not withstanding Ethan's comments above which would help us give better answers, it looks like the first part of your code could be made substantially simpler by using Python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and testing membership of these. This is much faster and easier than iterating through the list manually.

e.g.

```
#set with all the coordinates already used:
>>> s = {(1,1), (2,1), (3,4)}
# test different coordinates for membership of s
>>> (1,1) in s
True
>>> (4,5) in s
False
```